# To solve $ y'+y=|x|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the solution to the IVP $$y'+y=|x|, \ x \in \mathbb{R}, \ y(-1)=0$$

The general solution of the above problem is $y_{g}(x)=ce^{-x}$.

How to find the particular solution? As $|x|$ is not differentiable at origin. Is there any alternate way to get the solution?

Comment: You can follow the standard Ansatz. You don't need the right hand side to be differentiable.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: using the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) the equation can be rewritten as
$$
(e^{x}y(x))'=e^{x}|x|.
$$
Thus, you are left with writing down the solution to $w'(x)=f(x)$, $w(x_0)=0$ ($f$ continuous).

> $$w(x)=\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 3):

or use the variation of parameters method
$$y=y_c+y_p$$
we know that $y_c=ce^{-x}$

so
$$y_p=u(x)e^{-x}$$
$$y'_p=u'(x)e^{-x}-u(x)e^{-x}$$
substitute in the D.E to get
$$u(x)=\int|x|e^{x}dx=e^x(x-1)\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\operatorname{sgn}(x)+1$$
so the
$$y_p=(x-1)\operatorname{sgn}(x)+e^{-x}[\operatorname{sgn}(x)+1]$$

Comment: The anti-derivative that you compute, by its basic properties, has to be continuous at $x=0$. As your proposed solution does not satisfy this, it is wrong.

Comment: Consider instead $$u(x)=e^x(x-1)\operatorname{sgn}(x)+2\operatorname{Heaviside}(x).$$

Comment: A largely correct way to compute the integral and getting a continuous result is by partial integration and using that the Dirac delta distribution gets canceled by continuous functions having a zero at $x=0$. $$u(x)=|x|e^x-\int sign(x)e^x\,dx=sign(x)[xe^x -(e^x-1)]+ \int 2\delta(x)(e^x-1) \,dx=sign(x)[(x-1)e^x+1]+C.$$

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish the two cases whether $x < 0$ and $x \geq 0$ and see that the two solutions "matches" at the origin.

When $x < 0$, $y'+y=-x$ you look for a particular solution of the form $y_p(x)=ax+b$ and gives you $a+ax+b=-x$, therefore $a=-1$ and $b=-a=1$ so $y_p(x)=-x+1$

When $x \geq 0$, $y'+y=x$ you look for a particular solution of the form $y_p(x)=ax+b$ and gives you $a+ax+b=x$, therefore $a=1$ and $b=-a=-1$ so $y_p(x)=x-1$

So now we have $y(x)=c_1e^{-x}-x+1$ for $x < 0$ and $y(x)=c_2e^{-x}+x-1$ for $x \geq 0$

The initial condition $y(-1)=0$ gives us $0=c_1e+1+1$ i.e. $c_1=-2e^{-1}$ and we get $y(x)=-2e^{-x-1}-x+1$ for $x < 0$.

Now we want our two solutions to match at the origin so $-2e^{-1}+1=c_2-1$, so $c_2=2(1-e^{-1})$ and we get $y(x)=2(1-e^{-1})e^{-x}+x-1$ when $x \geq 0$

Finally we can write our solution $$y(x)=-2e^{-x+1}-x+1 \ \mathrm{when\ } x < 0$$

$$y(x)=2(1-e^{-1})e^{-x}+x-1 \ \mathrm{when \ }x \geq 0 $$

Comment: The solution on the positives uses the hypothesis that the solution is continuous. This is not required in the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : A solution to an ODE, especially a continuous one, is always a continuous, differentiable function. How could it be a solution of a *differential* equation if it did not have a derivative?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree with the previous comment. By default, with no distribution solution being mentioned, the solution to an ODE is implicitly assumed to be a function that is smooth enough so that all the derivatives in the equation are classically defined.

Comment: @LutzL: by having a limited domain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust By that reasoning, a solution on $(-1.1,-0.9)$ also solves the task. Why even bother going close to $x=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust we can see from the question that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

To find a particular solution, you can explore the Ansatz

$$y=|x|,$$ giving $$y'+y=\text{sgn}(x)+|x|.$$

This is valid on the whole real line, except at the origin, where the discontinuity is unavoidable. So compensating the sign term, there is a piecewise solution,

$$y=|x|-\text{sgn}(x).$$

The rest is standard.

> $$x<0\to y=-\dfrac2ee^{-x}-x+1,\\x>0\to y=ce^{-x}+x-1$$ where $c$ is unknown.

Comment: If no continuity at $x=0$ is ensured, then the interval $[0,\infty)$ does not belong to the domain of the solution. The left and right limits at $x=0$ are trivially computable, so that the $c$ for an extended continuously differentiable solution is very well known.

Comment: @LutzL: I know. I initially stated *undefined* for the positive solution, but then changed my mind to avoid bad comments :-) Some other answers seem to *require* a continuous extension, but this is artificial.

Comment: But by basic properties of linear ODE with constant or continuous coefficients and continuous right sides, the maximal solution of this problem has domain $\Bbb R$. There is nothing undefined.

Comment: @LutzL: you said it, *maximal*.

Answer (score -2):

$$y'+y=|x|$$
Solving without condition :

Case $x>0 \quad:\quad y'+y=x \qquad y=c_1e^{-x}+x-1$

Case $x<0 \quad:\quad y'+y=-x \qquad y=c_2e^{-x}-x+1$
$$y=ce^{-x}+(x-1)\text{ sgn}(x)$$
sgn$(x)$ is the function sign of $x$

The function is discontinuous at $x=0$.

[image]

The discontinuous curve represented is only an example for a particular value of $c_1=c_2=c$. Of course they are an infinity of solutions. Don't confuse this general equation with the solution below which is strictly the answer corresponding to the condition $y(-1)=0$.

With condition $\quad y(-1)=0$ :

$y(-1)=0=c_2e^{-(-1)}+((-1)-1)(-1)=c_2e+2\quad;\quad c_2=-\frac{2}{e}$ 
$$y=-2e^{-x-1}-x+1 \quad \text{in } x\leq 0. \tag 1$$

In $x>0$ :

Condition $y(0)=1-2e^{-1}$

$y(0)=1-2e^{-1}=c_1e^{-0}+0-1=c_1-1\quad;\quad c_1=2-2e^{-1}$
$$y=2(1-e^{-1})e^{-x}+x-1 \quad \text{in } x\geq 0. \tag 2$$

[image]

Note after the comments :

The above solution Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ is the same as the LutzL's solution written on a different form :
$$y=ce^{-x}+sign(e^{-x}-1+x)$$
with $c=1+2e^{-1}$.

Comment: As the right side is a continuous function, the solution of the ODE has to be a continuously differentiable function. Your solution with a jump is wrong, you need to adjust $c_1,c_2$ so that at least continuity at $x=0$ is guaranteed, continuity of the derivative then follows. Thus $c_1-1=c_2+1=c$ gives $$y=ce^{-x}+sign(x)(e^{-x}-1+x).$$

Comment: It sounds weird to introduce a discontinuous particular solution and then fight against the discontinuity to make it well-defined.

Comment: As it is clearly written in my answer the solutions with discontinuity is for the problem without condition. With the specified condition the solution given at the end of my answer is a continuous function and the equation given in my answer is exactly the same as the equation given by LutzL.

Comment: @JJacquelin Right, but a general solution (without IVP) has still to be differentiable. The OP sounds like a freshman problem without any distribution being involved.

Comment: I cannot see were is the problem. The derivative is well defined : $y'(0)=2e^{-1}-1$ for Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ of my answer and as well for the LutzL's answer in comment. This is also the same equation in the answer from user289143.

Comment: At a jump discontinuity, as in your first function at $x=0$, the function is not continuous, thus even less differentiable. That left and right limits of the derivative exist and coincide does not matter if the left and right limits of the function values do not coincide, look at the basic definition of a limit of difference quotients.

Comment: Consider the equation $y'=2|x|$. We can solve it separately for positive and for negative $x$: $x^2+C$ vs $-x^2+C$, but if we are looking for one solution in $\mathbb{R}$ then we need to sew together two solutions at $x=0$ to make them as one *classical* solution. It is no good to consider $x^2+1$ for positive and $-x^2-1$ for negative $x$. P.S. By the way, it is not good even for distributions.

Comment: OK, if we are looking for one solution in $\mathbb{R}$  then forget the first part of my answer.